# Did Sarah Fenn's spell cause Michael's psychopathy?

Tags: sanctuary-a-witchs-tale

On *Sanctuary: A Witch's Tale*, Abigail Whithall claims to her husband that she asked Sarah to cast a spell on him, and that this spell caused him to become callous and essentially psychopathic.
On the one hand, we know that Sarah did cast a spell to help him get ahead in his job and both Abigail and Michael seemed to quite genuinely believe that the spell was responsible for his psychopathic behavior. We also know Sarah cast a variety of other ethically prohibited spells, some of which had effects beyond what she had anticipated.

On the other hand, though, we have the counterexample of Daniel Whithall: even though Sarah, herself a witch and responsible for his resurrection, believed that her spell had caused his sexually predatory behavior, Pierre presented compelling evidence that that was not the case.

So which is true?